# Excel formula to pull data and numbers from one row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with names of items in columns B7:B100. I want to pull that name to another sheet if column G has an x in it. Then on the same sheet in another column I want to pull a dollar figure in the same row but from column AN. I have tried several functions I keep coming up with #value.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far? It's also a bit unclear what you mean by "I want to pull a dollar figure in the same row but from column AN"

Comment: Looks like a simple `If-Index-Match` combination. You can try to read about these functions and you'll get the idea. :)

Comment: I am trying to copy and paste from my excel but it doesn't look like that when I post it. Makes it really hard to read any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You could Filter your table B6:AN100.   Filter col G for "x".  Then copy the results to your new worksheet.  Or you could use the formula below:

Items, Prices and Xs are all defined Names:

```
Items   Refers To:  =Sheet1!$B$7:$B$100
Prices  Refers To:  =Sheet1!$AN$7:$AN$100
Xs      Refers To:  =Sheet1!$G$7:$G$100
```

The following are Array formulas, entered in some cell on your other sheet and filled down until you see blanks being returned.

```
For the Item List:   =IFERROR(INDEX(Items,SMALL((Xs = "x")*ROW(Items),ROWS($1:1)+COUNTBLANK(Xs))),"")
For the Price List:  =IFERROR(INDEX(Prices,SMALL((Xs = "x")*ROW(Items),ROWS($1:1)+COUNTBLANK(Xs))),"")
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **{**...**}** around the formula.